# Share root slug for Child Page and Custom Post Type (prioritizing child pages over posts)

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting

Let's suppose a Custom Post Type called "Whatever", which will have a root slug set to "whatever".

This makes all posts of type "whatever" be available at `site.url/whatever/post-name`

I also want a parent page called Whatever to be available at `site.url/whatever`

To achieve that, I must create the page with said slug and also set the `has_archive` property to false, when registering the "Whatever" CPT.

So far so good.

Now, I want to have some specific child pages for the page "Whatever", and I want them to be available at `site.url/whatever/child-page-name`

This last step is not working because when accessing that url, WordPress tries to load a CPT of type "Whatever" with name "child-page-name". And it does not exist.

What I want to do is to prioritize pages during the loading process, so that if a child page of "Whatever" exists with the requested name, it should always be loaded (even if a CPT exists with said name).

I don't know where to start. I thought about having the single-whatever.php file look for a page with the requested post name. But, I don't know what to do with that information if the page exists. Should I redirect? Filter the loaded template? Here is where I am stuck, and any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The EASIEST way that you could do this with your set up is create the "child-page-name" as one of your actual post types.

Comment: @rudtek Thanks for the suggestion, but in this case I also need the page to use page templates, which are different than the post-type template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to have some specific child pages for the page "Whatever", and I want them to be available at `site.url/whatever/child-page-name`

> What I want to do is to prioritize pages during the loading process, so that if a child page of "Whatever" exists with the requested name, it should always be loaded (even if a CPT exists with said name).

If the child pages have to be Pages (posts of the `page` type), then you can use the [`parse_request` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/parse_request/) to conditionally change the request type, which in your case is from a custom post type request to a standard (child) Page request, which means that [`is_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) would return true and WordPress would also load the correct template for Pages like `page-whatever.php`.

***Working example**, tried & tested on WordPress 5.8.1:*

Note: [`get_page_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_uri/) is used to retrieve the "directory" path of the child Page, so if `parent` is the parent Page slug and `child` is the child Page slug, then the path would be `parent/child`.

```php
add_action( 'parse_request', 'my_parse_request' );
function my_parse_request( $wp ) {
    $post_type = 'whatever'; // set the post type slug
    // and the "whatever" below is the Page slug

    // This code checks if the path of the current request/page URL begins with
    // "whatever/" as in https://example.com/whatever/child-page-name and also
    // https://example.com/whatever/child-page-name/page/2 (paginated request).
    // We also check if the post_type var is the post type set above.
    if ( preg_match( '#^whatever/#', $wp->request ) &&
        isset( $wp->query_vars['post_type'], $wp->query_vars['name'] ) &&
        $post_type === $wp->query_vars['post_type']
    ) {
        $posts = get_posts( array(
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'name'      => $wp->query_vars['name'],
        ) );

        // If a (child) Page with the same name/slug exists, we load the Page,
        // regardless the post type post exists or not.
        if ( ! empty( $posts ) ) {
            $wp->query_vars['pagename'] = get_page_uri( $posts[0] );

            unset( $wp->query_vars['post_type'], $wp->query_vars['name'],
                $wp->query_vars[ $post_type ] );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this excellent solution.